Prove that we can have $k\ge 4 T +4$ with $5^{k+1} T \le \sqrt n$ and $T = o(\log n)$
We have: $5^{k+1} T \le \sqrt n$ and we know that $T=o(\log n)$ and $n$ is some big integer. According to the paper I'm reading it should be possible to prove that $k$ can be greater than $4T + 4$. I'd like to verify the calculus myself but I can't manage to finish it:
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
& 5^{k+1} \epsilon \log n < 5^{k+1} T  \le \sqrt n \\
\Longrightarrow  & (k+1)\log 5 < \log \big( \frac{\sqrt n}{\epsilon\log n} \big) \\
\Longrightarrow & k+1 < \frac{1}{\log 5} \big(\log \sqrt n - \log\epsilon\log n \big)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I have the feeling (maybe incorrect?) that because $\epsilon$ can be chosen as small as we want $-\log \epsilon \log n$ can be extremely big. But I feel I miss something here.
Edit: this claim can be found in  dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3662158.3662794 , page 9 (114), in the proof of theorem 1.1 (below fig 5).

What is the source for the claim? I get that $k$ can be of order $\log(n)$ but I think the constant needs to be smaller than $1/(2\log(5))$, in particular smaller than 1, not 4 as in the claim you stated.

@quarague https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3662158.3662794 , page 9 (114), in the proof of theorem 1.1 (below fig 5). When I wrote this comment I realized I made an error that may be crucial for the question, we need $k>4T+4$ which is probably not the same thing as $k>4 \log n +4$.
